# Python, sympy: A simple set of equations involving repeated powers gives nonsensical (to me!) answers

Tags: python, sympy, root, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I am new to both python and the sympy module so some of my code may be a bit 'primitive'. This is also my first use of Stackoverflow so forgive any use errors. I have included an entire test function which can be called using TEST() [this is a simplified version of my actual work, but displays the problem I am getting]. Essentially I have three equations:
(1) `lamb=h/sqrt(k*T)`
(2) lamb=d
(3)`d**3=k*T/P`
and I wish to amalgamate them and solve for T. This is quite easy to do by hand without using the sympy package, but, as I say, I am trying to learn it. When I run the code, instead of getting the answer `T=h**(6/5)P**(2/5)/k`, I get a series of complex numbers. I have no problem if, instead of solving for T, I solve for h. Moreover, if I change equation (3) to, say `d**4=k*T/P`, the result I get is correct. The problem seems to arise out of the fact that in trying to solve the equation, the powers of k and T (in the equations) are the same. In fact, if I replace `k*T` by the single variable kT throughout, I get a sensible solution.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong and what I should be doing instead?

MORE INFO:  In fact the correct solution is present!  It's the [4]th answer.  But why am I getting the other (complex number) answers (and how do I select the real valued one)?

MORE THOUGHTS (16/-6/20 18:15):  Presumably it is because k and T independently can have 5 roots (because of the 6/5 power).  So is there a way of saying only real roots should be considered?

PaulJ

```
        def TEST():
            import sympy
            from sympy import symbols,Symbol,root,integrate,diff,Derivative,N,I,var,latex
            from sympy import sympify,Function,Eq,solve
            from sympy import pi,exp
    
            print("")
            print("TEST")

            #Declare other variables (avoid C,O,S,I,N,E, and Q)
            var('d h k T P lamb kT',positive=True)

            Eq1=Eq(lamb,h/(root(T,2,0)*root(k,2,0)))
            print("Eq1=",Eq1)
            Eq2=Eq(lamb,d)
            print("Eq2=",Eq2)
            Eq3=Eq(d**3,k*T/P)
            print("Eq3=",Eq3)

            res_d=solve(Eq3,d)[0]
            print("res_d=",res_d)
            Eq4=Eq2.subs(d,res_d)
            print("Eq4=",Eq4)
            res_lamb=solve(Eq4,lamb)[0]
            print("res_lamb=",res_lamb)

            Eq5=Eq1.subs(lamb,res_lamb)
            print("Eq5=",Eq5)
            res_P=solve(Eq5,P)[0]
            print("res_P=",res_P)
            Eq6=Eq(res_P,P)
            print("Eq6=",Eq6)
            print("Try solving for (this works) h=",solve(Eq6,h)[0])
            print("Try solving for (this fails miserably) T=",solve(Eq6,T)[0])
            print("and in fact, the full miserable solution is...")
            res_T=solve(Eq6,T)[0]
            print("res_T=",solve(Eq6,T))
            print("")
            print("The problem seems to be that the powers of T and k in Eq6 are the same.")
            print("If I change the Eq3 so that it's d**4 = k*T/P I get a sensible solution")
    
            print("")
            print("Now try with k*T replaced by kT throughout")
            Eq1a=Eq(lamb,h/(root(kT,2,0)))
            print("Eq1a=",Eq1a)
            Eq2a=Eq(lamb,d)
            print("Eq2a=",Eq2a)
            Eq3a=Eq(d**3,kT/P)
            print("Eq3a=",Eq3a)

            resa_d=solve(Eq3a,d)[0]
            print("resa_d=",resa_d)
            Eq4a=Eq2.subs(d,resa_d)
            print("Eq4a=",Eq4a)
            resa_lamb=solve(Eq4a,lamb)[0]
            print("res_lamb=",resa_lamb)

            Eq5a=Eq1a.subs(lamb,resa_lamb)
            print("Eq5a=",Eq5a)
            resa_P=solve(Eq5a,P)[0]
            print("res_P=",resa_P)
            Eq6a=Eq(resa_P,P)
            print("Eq6a=",Eq6a)
            print("Try solving for (this works) h=",solve(Eq6a,h)[0])
            print("Try solving for (this work!) kT=",solve(Eq6a,kT)[0])

    
            return
```

Comment: Setting your symbols as positive as you have done is usually enough to avoid complex roots. You can also try using `solveset(domain=Reals)` instead of `solve`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I discovered Set=solveset(Eq6,T,domain=S.Reals) and this worked a treat.  I had to use list(Set) to get at the solution.  I am now looking at what happens when I get all 5 solutions eg Set5=solveset(solveset(Eq6,T).  I now get a ConditionSet back and I can't seem to extract the solutions via list.  But I'll keep investigating.

Comment: You may need to dig into `.args` to get the solution out of the ConditionSet.

Comment: I did have a little dig around the .args feature but it seemed I had to iterate into the ConditionSet again and again and to be honest I wasn't sure where I was heading.  So I'm giving up on solveset(...S.Complexes) as all I really need (at the moment, at least) is solveset(...S.Reals).  But thank you for you advice.